# cursor stoppropagagtion on child elements

Tags: jquery, cursor, stoppropagation

So, I'm using the following to make a container div link to another website:

```
 $("#container").click(function(e) {
    var senderElement = e.target;
    //check if sender is the DIV element
    window.location = 'http://domain.com';
    return true;
});
 $("#container *").click(function(e) {
   //do something
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

How can I make a cursor appear as a 'pointer'- `$('selector').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );`- only for the parent (#container)?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('#container').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' ).children('*').css( 'cursor', 'default' )` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff - close! appears that the cursor behaves as intended, except that one must first click on a child element (non-anchor) first, then hover over the parent in order for the cursor to become a 'pointer'. if allowing the page to just load, simply hovering over the parent element does not change the cursor to 'pointer'- even if the browser window was active.